# python misreading filepath name

Tags: python, python-3.x, listdir

I want to iterate over a number of files in the L: drive on my computer in a folder called 11109. This is my script:

```
for filename in os.listdir('L:\11109'):
    print(filename.split('-')[1])
```

However the error message comes back as :

```
File "L:/OMIZ/rando.py", line 12, in <module>
for filename in os.listdir('L:\11109'):

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
'L:I09'
```

Its reading the L:\ 11109 fine but the error message said the path specified is L:I09?

Comment: I suggest that you use raw strings for Windows paths. FWIW, `\111` is an octal escape sequence, and `'\111'` is the same string as `'I'`. 111 is octal for 73, and 73 is the codepoint of `'I'`, that is, `chr(73)` returns `'I'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use raw strings or escape the backslash, otherwise `\111` is resolved to `I`:

```
a = 'L:\11109'
print(a)  # shows that indeed 'L:I09'

b = r'L:\11109'
print(b)  # prints 'L:\11109'

c = 'L:\\11109'  # will be understood correctly by open()
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can do like this

```
for filename in os.listdir('L:/11109'):
    print(filename.split('-')[1])
```